# Auto adjusting the x and y axis of the image in iphone

Tags: iphone

Ha ii  everybody,i have a requirement that i have a button in my app with text its text changes dynamically according to different actions on the app,that means if the button title is god on other action it changed to some lengthy text like stack-overflow or something,and i have a small downarrow image on the right side of this button ,like  the username that displays in the main header of the stack-overflow,a downarrow on the left-side with the username,like that,but my problem is i put this image in a fixed position the image never changed the position,if the god is the title of the button the image is too far from the button if the text is stack-overflow the image will hide by the text,i need a solution how to auto-adjust the position of the image according to the text length of the button near this image.I hope you genius developers understand my question.Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [buttonText sizeWithFont:button.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:maxLabelSizeForAdd lineBreakMode:button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode]; 
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(150, 10, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
```

Assign this rect to button
For image

```
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(150+button.frame.origin.x+10, height, imageWidth,imageHeight);
```

Assign this rect to image. In this expectedLabelSize calculates size of string and according to text size you can adjust button position. As I am new to iphone development I hope this will work for you..

Comment: first two lines before button frame declaration and other one before ur image frame  declaration.

Comment: CGSize maxLabelSizeForAdd = CGSizeMake(150, 9999); And NSString *buttonText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter]forState:UIControlStateNormal]‌​;

Comment: CGSize maxLabelSizeForAdd = CGSizeMake(150, 9999);
     NSString *buttonText = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [buttonText sizeWithFont:_btnChapterSelection.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:maxLabelSizeForAdd lineBreakMode:_btnChapterSelection.titleLabel.lineBreakMode]; 
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(150, 10, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height); ….i put this in my view didload method,but how to assing rect with my image img?thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

Find the width of the button text. Set the origin of the image view according to the width.